# Objective-c replaceObjectAtIndex not working because of array in array structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

i have an array and i get value with  this codes:

```
NSString *status = [[Sweetresponse objectAtIndex:path.row] objectAtIndex:9];
```

i wanna change this value :

```
[[Sweetresponse objectAtIndex:path.row] replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:@"liked"];
```

But its not working because this structure is array in array. how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Keep an array of custom objects instead.  It will be better in the long term.

Comment: its not working means? Do you get any error/crash/ something ?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: FYI - please follow standard naming conventions. Only class names should start with uppercase letters. Method names and variable names should always start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `NSArray` is immutable. You have to make it mutable.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableResponse = [Sweetresponse mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *mutableResponseItems = [[mutableResponse objectAtIndex:path.row] mutableCopy];
// replace at the index
[mutableResponseItems replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:@"liked"];
// create immutables and replace it with our new array
mutableResponse[path.row] = [mutableResponseItems copy];
// set `Sweetresponse` (assuming it is an NSArray)
Sweetresponse = [mutableResponse copy];
```

edit: I have no idea what `Sweetresponse` really is, here I'm assuming it's a `NSArray`

@trojanfoe has a point with parsing this response into custom objects would lead to cleaner code and also simpler object modification.

Comment: `mutableCopy`?  Are you sure?

Comment: yes, `mutableCopy` returns a new instance that is mutable. it's important to create a non-mutable copy of that instance to restore immutability.

Comment: Well you could always create a mutable array of mutable arrays up front, and dispense with copying thereafter.

Comment: while you're right, it's not encouraged as you could end up with weird values, also race conditions are quite common with mutable objects.

Comment: Really?  That's news to me.